# Dynamic PHP images requesting url

Tags: php, gd

I have a PHP script that generates dynamic images using GD. The image may be accessed remotely via, for example, http://mysite.com/scripts/phpimages.php

Any remote website such as example.com could able to render this image in its client side HTML img tag. For example:

```
<!-- http://example.com/about.html -->
<img src="http://mysite.com/scripts/phpimages.php" />
```

What I need that my script able to know the URL of the image requested page i.e http://example.com/about.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
 echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
```

To prevent errors,

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    echo $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

Comment: Instead of echoing it, the value should be stored.

Comment: well, I just gave him a way to do that. Not sure how he is going to use it :)

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Yes it is that I really want to do. Store it in a database to know others websites render my image.